# How to get SQL Query for the changes in database schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am not a database programmer but I have a big database that contains many tables. My database programmer left the project that we were doing together. So all the load came upon me for completing that project. On my local server I made many changes to my app's database schema. I noted all the changes in the notebook to implement them on main server. But I want a quick method to update database on main server with those changes. So I was wondering if there exists any way of generating query for only those changes that are done on local server using SQL Server Management Studio or some other tool?

Comment: You need to generate scripts for the changes and test them on dev server so that when you go to production you know they will work.

Comment: RedGate has a tool to compare schema between two databases - it's called [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/).  You could use a free trial of that to complete your project.

Comment: Generally your best bet is to write and keep the script up to date as you make the changes on the dev environment.

Comment: If you use visual studio, you can create a database project and have the schema in source control. Then you can perform schema comparison/updates between local/server/source controlled versions.

Comment: I completely agree with @bowlturner : if the changes were all done in SQL scripts that were numbered sequentially, then you would just apply those changes, in order, to any other system to bring it up to the same state. Then you wouldn't need separate notes: the SQL scripts would be your notes, just functional ones :). While there are several tools that do DB comparisons, it is generally not a good idea to rely upon them to sync changes, especially when there are complex dependencies and even data involved.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL compare tool should provide you with a good solution to start with

[DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/) provides a free alternative to Redgates [SQL Compare] (http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)

Going forward you should keep a source controled version of the database.

Our company also stores the db version in the database and uses a versioned update script
whenever a live db needs updated.